# Microsoft SQL Server BI

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssas

What edition of sql server contains all BI , analysis, integration, reporting.

Does the install of SQl server for BI create a report database, reportdatabase tempdb  and does analysis and integration need database components.

I guess I asking what do I need to install to get a sql server database running with BI. Is it just sql server and SSDT tools or during the install of SQL Server do I need to select analysis, reporting, etc

Comment: For my edit, I changed the word Version to Edition - Edition, as @benjamin moskovits indicates is the product feature set (Enterprise/Standard/Web/Express/Developer). Version is tied to a "name": 2000/2005/2008/2008 R2/2012/2014/2016/2017/v.Next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four editions of SQL Server (as of SQL Server 2017) - Enterprise, Standard, Web and Express (Developer is Enterrpise, is free (sometimes there is a $50 media fee but cannot be used in production). All four support Reporting Services.

Please see the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017

If you are going to run SSRS and SSDT do yourself a favor and select these products during the install. Initially the databases are not that large. You probably can run SSDT from the command line  without the install but you will run into all kinds of unnecessary issues if you don't install it. You can turn off the service if you are not using that feature.

BI is fully supported in Enterprise and many of the features I have used are available in Standard. Please see the following to compare editions for BI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-analysis-services-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017